# Suppose that $p$ and $q$ are both prime numbers where $p > q$. Show that $p - q$ and $p + q$ cannot both be perfect squares.

Tags: prime-numbers, square-numbers

It's a lot harder when its adding and subtracting because I can't use prime factorization to prove anything. I've gotten a little bit, as all primes (with the exception of $2$) are odd, and 
odd + odd = even
odd - odd = even
I feel like you need to prove via contradiction, though Im not sure how to go about doing that. Any ideas?

Comment: If $p+q = m^2$ and $p-q = n^2$ then $m^2 - n^2 = (p+q)-(p-q)$.  Do you see why there may be issues with that?

Comment: Hint 1:  $(p+q) - (p-q) = 2q$.   And Hint 2: $m^2 - n^2 = (m-n)(m+n)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume $q \ge 3$. If $p+q$ and $p-q$ are both squares, then $p-q$ and $p+q$ are both *even* squares, which means both are divisible by $4$, which means then that $p+q - (p-q)=2q$ must be divisible by $4$. But this cannot be i.e., $2q=(p+q)-(p-q)$ cannot be divisible by $4$, as $q$ is an odd number as $q$ is a  prime at least $3$.

[Note that I only used that $p$ and $q$ are **odd**.]

As for $q=2$, note that with the exception of the pairs $1,4$, the absolute value of the difference between every two integral squares is at least $5$. So with $q=2$, note that $p+2$ and $p-2$ cannot both be squares as they differ by only $4<5$.